# Customize the dictionary iterator in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterator

I have a Python dictionary which consists of a set of objects. I would like to iterate through all of the objects in the dictionary which satisfy some condition. I was wondering if it is possible to customize the default dictionary iterator?

So instead of needing to write:

```
for key, value in objects.items():
    if <condition>:
        #Do something with object.
```

I could just write:

```
#Get all object which satisfy <condition>
for key, value in objects.items():
    #do something with object
```

Comment: No, but you can filter, etc.

Comment: how would you except to pick some keys with condition when you won't going to check all keys?

Comment: You could subclass from `UserDict`, but that's not worth it in this case. It's more flexible to just filter outside of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` clause is probably the clearest *and* most efficient solution.

You can, however, use a generator expression. This does **not** pre-calculate in-scope items, but gives a lazy iterable which lets you iterate in-scope items one at a time.

For example, given a condition defined in `func` as a function of key and value:

```
# iterable of objects satisfying condition
objects_filtered = ((k, v) for k, v in objects.items() if func(k, v))

for key, value in objects_filtered:
    # do something
```

If your dictionary is small, or lazy iteration is not required, you can use a list comprehension instead:

```
objects_filtered = [(k, v) for k, v in objects.items() if func(k, v)]
```

For iterables that fit comfortably in memory, list comprehensions are usually more efficient. But they serve different purposes: if you need a lazy iterator use a generator / generator expression; if you need values in memory, use a list.

Customizing the default dictionary iterator seems unnecessary for this task.

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!